# Best way to download excel sheet using ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, download, datatables

I am using the below code to download the excel file:

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "MBQ.xls"));
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
DataTable dt = BindDatatable();
string str = string.Empty;
foreach (DataColumn dtcol in dt.Columns)
{
    Response.Write(str + dtcol.ColumnName);
    str = "\t";
}
Response.Write("\n");
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    str = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        Response.Write(str + Convert.ToString(dr[j]));
        str = "\t";
    }
    Response.Write("\n");
}
Response.End();
```

In my case, the table has more than 800k records. I am applying more filters before downloading the excel sheet. What is the best way to download a excel sheet from the datatable which has hundreds of thousands of rows?

Comment: The output is not a valid Excel document, is it?

Comment: You are not generating an Excel spreadsheet. You are actually exporting a TSV file. The correct MIME type is `text/tab-separated-values` and the correct extension is `.tsv` (though many consider `.csv` also acceptable for TSV files).

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Yes.. I also tried HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

Comment: @Dai: How to modify the above to download successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly since that isn't an excel spreadsheet but a tab-separated-values file (which can be opened in excel and does what you want), then don't lie in the header as that can only bring confusion:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "MBQ.csv"));
Response.ContentType = "text/tab-separated-values";
```

(Strictly ".csv" is an extension normally defined as being for comma-separated-values rather than tab, but it's more commonly set up to open in Excel, LibreOffice Calc, or whatever spreadsheet program people have installed, and they'll generally consider CSV and TSV as variants of each other).

Secondly, don't buffer. You have `Response.Buffer = true;` set to explicitly make sure you keep masses of data in memory before sending it, you want to do the opposite, so `Response.Buffer = false;` is the way to go.

You might find it better still to explicitly call `Response.Flush()` every couple of hundred or thousand rows:
int rowCount = 0;

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    str = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        Response.Write(str + Convert.ToString(dr[j]));
        str = "\t";
    }
    Response.Write("\n");
    if (unchecked(++rowCount % 1024 == 0))
        Response.Flush();
}
```

Experiment with higher or lower values than `1024`. Higher sends larger chunks which is inefficient in needing more memory to hold it, but efficient in the actual sending of the chunk is snappier, so the optimal value will be a matter of finding the best balance between those two factors.

Comment: And generate an Excel with several sheets ?

Comment: @Kiquenet if you want to do that you'll want to produce an actual Excel file, which would be a very different problem to the querent here starting with code that produced TSV files.